# Accessing laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am working on a project and using Laravel 5.3, I have some problem in accessing laravel relationships.
Like I have set up these relationships - 
On user modal -

```
public function likes() {
    return $this->hasMany(Like::class, 'user_id');
}

public function dislikes() {
    return $this->hasMany(Dislike::class, 'user_id');
}

public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}

public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}

public function replies() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

On Posts modal -

```
public function likes() {
    return $this->morphMany(Like::class,'likeable');
}

public function dislikes() {
    return $this->morphMany(Dislike::class, 'dislikeable');
}

public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Now here is my question. Suppose one user has 10 posts, and each of them has 20 likes and 10 dislikes, then how I can show total likes and total dislikes on his posts with relationships, I know how to access likes and dislikes for each post in my view --

```
$post->likes->count()
$post->dislikes->count()
```

Again I can access likes and Dislikes made by any user, as I have method on user modal to access those and I will do something like this in my model

```
Auth::user()->likes->count();
Auth::user()->dislikes->count();
```

But I want to show the number of total posts with total comments, replies, likes and dislikes on those in number format.
Can you help me on how to access those through relationships.

Answer (score 0):

The short and simple answer is: Work backwards.

```
Dislike::whereHas('posts', function($q) {
    return $q->where('user_id', $this->id);
});
```

Now you will have all of the dislikes for a particular user across all of their posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with` statement to use Eloquent relationships, like below

In User controller

```
 User:: with(['posts'])->get();  //this with will fetch the user with all the posts and post likes/dislikes
```

In user model

```
public function posts() {
      return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->with(['likes','dislikes']); //this will join likes and disliks based on the relation given in post model
  }
```

In post model

```
 public function likes() {
    return $this->hasMany(Like::class,'likeable'); //relation of post with likes
  }



public function dislikes() {
    return $this->hasMany(Dislike::class, 'dislikeable'); //relation of post with dislikes
  }
```